# Can not set background for RelativeLayout?

Tags: android-layout, android, android-background

In my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/theme"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

I see in the Graphical layout. The theme was set as I want, and I run in Galaxy Note 3, it just the white one. While I set the other image, it is Ok. I don't know the reason. Can you tell me what should I do?

Comment: whats is that theme? can you try setting android:background="#00AA00"

Comment: Your code is correct, I think..May be your image has some problem or some error there..Try deleting the image and add it again to drawable folder..

Comment: Try doing it dynamically and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

May be your image has very high resolution , or very low resolution, its really hard to tell from the code , but from what you have written , when you set some other image it runs fine, its the only conclusion.